# Determine the Maximum Dimension of the Domain of an Injective Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have these two exercises where I have to determine the dimension of the domain of an injective linear mapping.

1. Let $W_2$ be the vector space of the upper-triangular $2 \times 2$ matrices, and let $T: R^n \to W_2$ be an injective linear mapping. What values ​​could $n$ take?
2. Let $W_3$ be the vector space of the upper-triangular $3 \times 3$ matrices, and let $T: R^n \to W_3$ be an injective linear mapping. What values ​​could $n$ take?

I thought to proceed in this way.

- These are injective linear transformations, so we have that $\dim(\ker(T)) = 0.$
- By the Rank-Nullity Theorem, we have that $n = \dim(R^n) = \dim(\mathrm{im}(T)) + \dim(\ker(T)).$
- We know the dimensions of the spaces $W_2$ and $W_3.$
- We have that $\dim(\mathrm{im}(T)) \leq \dim(W)$ because $\mathrm{im}(T) 
   \subseteq W.$

Through these observations, I can conclude that

1. exercise 1 has solutions $ 0 \leq n \leq 3$ and
2. exercise 2 has solutions $ 0 \leq n \leq 6.$

But I'm not really sure about these solutions. Is the procedure correct?

Comment: Why do you eliminate the $0$ value?

Comment: @Bernard No specific reason, i didn't thought about it. Do tou think that it's correct how i solved it?

Comment: A bit long , but correct. I'd just say that the injectivity condition implies $n\le \dim W$, and compute $\dim W$ in each case.